# How to add products and sliders?

Tags: magento1.9.3

I'm adding products and slider only . I want what are things I need to know in magento 1.9.3 and where I can get material to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is official documentaion for Magento beginners , you can check below link :

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-1.html

Also do some research on Magento 1 and Magento 2 and decide which one to learn.....

Answer (score 2):

In Addition to @Baby in Magento answer, You can also follow the below tutorials for M1 as learning base:

https://magentotherightway.com/

https://blog.magestore.com/magento-tutorial/

http://www.coolryan.com/magento/